# Differentiate extern functions in Doxygen SQLite3 output

Tags: sqlite, doxygen

I would like to know if there is a way to differentiate between an 'extern' declaration of a function and a function definition in SQLite3 output of Doxygen. From what I gather, there is a table by the name of 'memberdef' which has several properties of the member and all functions are indexed here. Is there a way to differentiate a extern function declaration with the function definition? If there isn't a way, then it would be nice if there was a field in memberdef (0/1, similar to static and inline) which would account for 'extern' function declarations.

Comment: As far as I can tell this information is not stored by doxygen. For a function (at least when we are speaking of e.g. C / Cpp) I don't think it makes a lot of sense (nowadays) to have the word extern, just as a small help for the reader (and maybe the linker).

Comment: Yeah you are right. All functions which are defined are by default extern functions. We can have it for the variables though.

Comment: For the variables it is indeed missing, but see https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8533 (this was based in this question although the question was only speaking of functions).

Comment: The pull request  https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8533 regarding the extern variable has been integrated in the master version of doxygen.